# How do I find the sum of even integers if the sequence is not separated by 1 between values?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

I have an example sequence: [7,10,13,16,19,22].

I want to find the sum of even integers.
I would like to find the number of even integers first, then find the average, and then multiply them both for the sum.

But this regular way will not work - e.g. a Sequence: [7,8,9,10,...,20,21,22]

number of even = (22-8)/2 + 1 = 8

Avg even = (8+22)/2 = 15

Sum even = 8 * 15 = 120

Additionally, if I had a sequence like [8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22]
I could use the same framework as above.

So it seems like if the interval is 1 or 2 between each value that I could use the framework from above.

Can I clarify if there is a framework for finding sum of even numbers in a sequence where the interval is not 1 or 2? Like my main question above.

Comment: If your interval is even then all numbers in the sequence are odd or all numbers are even. If your interval is odd then your sequence contain interleaving odd and even numbers. In this case you can just take every second number in the sequence starting from first even number.

Comment: How will you find the number of even # in this sequence formulaically?

Comment: Let $a_i=a_{i-1}+q$ with integer $a_1$, $q$. Number of even numbers in sequence $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ is $\lfloor\frac{n+1-a_1\ {\rm mod}\ 2}{2}\rfloor \cdot(q\ {\rm mod}\ 2)+n(1-a_1\ {\rm mod}\ 2)\cdot(1-q\ {\rm mod}\ 2)$, where $i\ {\rm mod}\ 2 = t$ if $i\equiv t \pmod 2$ and $0\leq t \leq 1$.